# Why doesn't my v-if work

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work

I have the following but generates an error Property or method "isloading" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

```
<b-card v-if="isloading">
   <h2>Loading ...</h2>
</b-card>
<b-card v-else>
  <case-summary :caseId='caseId'></case-summary>
</b-card>
```

I have defined in my data:

```
data () {
    return {
      isLoading: true
    }
  },
```

And calling as follows

```
  async asyncData ({ params, store, isLoading=true }) {
        const thisCaseId = store.dispatch('cases/getCases', params.caseId ); 
        isLoading = false
        return { thisCaseId}
      }
```

Comment: `isloading` != `isLoading`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in isloading. Shouldn't that be isLoading?